# How to use wildcards in snakemake to merge with files with different wildcards?

Tags: python, bash, workflow, wildcard, snakemake

I’m using snakemake in order to analyze hundreds of files obtained from genomic sequencing. Depending on the quality of the sequencing for each sample, the platform had to sequence a second time some of these samples, resulting in four or eight file.

Looking like this:

```
multiple_subdirectories/BM1P149_A2/111353_BY/
├── 111353_BY_run757_AATGGTAG_S238_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
├── 111353_BY_run757_AATGGTAG_S238_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
├── 111353_BY_run757_AATGGTAG_S238_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
├── 111353_BY_run757_AATGGTAG_S238_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
├── 111353_BY_run758_AATGGTAG_S85_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
├── 111353_BY_run758_AATGGTAG_S85_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
├── 111353_BY_run758_AATGGTAG_S85_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
└── 111353_BY_run758_AATGGTAG_S85_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

With, in the folder BM1P149_A2, 96 samples like 111353_BY with 4 or 8 files, and 6 folders like BM1P149_A2.

I’m using snakemake wildcards to submit all of my data to the same analyzes. For the two first steps of my analyzes, trimming and mapping, I’ve had no issues since all the files are manipulated individually, the pipeline look like that for the trimming:

```
(PLAQUES,SAMPLES,IDS,PAIRED,) = glob_wildcards(config["dataDirInput"]+"{plaque}/{sample}/{id}_R{paire}_001.fastq.gz")

rule all:
  input: 
    expand(config["dataDirOutput"]+"{plaque}/{sample}/{id}_R{paire}_001_unpaired.fastq.gz", zip, plaque = PLAQUES, sample = SAMPLES, id = IDS, paire = PAIRED)

rule trimmomatic:
  input: 
    read1=config["dataDirInput"]+"{plaque}/{sample}/{id}_R1_001.fastq.gz",
    read2=config["dataDirInput"]+"{plaque}/{sample}/{id}_R2_001.fastq.gz"
  output: 
    read1_paired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{plaque}/{sample}/{id}_R1_001_paired.fastq.gz",
    read1_unpaired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{plaque}/{sample}/{id}_R1_001_unpaired.fastq.gz",
    read2_paired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{plaque}/{sample}/{id}_R2_001_paired.fastq.gz",
    read2_unpaired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{plaque}/{sample}/{id}_R2_001_unpaired.fastq.gz"
  threads: 20  
  resources:
    mem_mb = 20,
    time_min = 300 
  params: 
    env=config["trimmomatic_env"] # Here I'm using conda to call software trimmomatic for the trimming, and it's my way of associating  
  shell: "{params.env} PE {input.read1} {input.read2} {output.read1_paired} {output.read1_unpaired} {output.read2_paired} {output.read2_unpaired} ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq3-PE.fa:2:30:10:2:True
 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 MINLEN:36"
 
# in the config file, that I specify when I run the snakefile above

trimmomatic_env:
   "/directory_of_the_conda_environment". 

dataDirInput:                                                                                                                                                                              
   "/multiple_subdirectories/Sample_GData"  
                                                                                                                                                                                           
dataDirOutput:                                                                                                                                                                             
   "/multiple_subdirectories/Trimmed"
```

For the next steps, after the mapping I need to combine the mapped data from the two lanes and the two runs. The problem I'm confronted with, is that, using wildcards to analyze every single file at the beginning, I believe that for the rest of the analysis, the wildcards are set for one value (one of the two runs), and so I cannot merge them using wildcards.

To overcome that, what I tried to do is a if statement in the shell block of the rule in order to count the file and merge two or four files whether there are two runs for this sample or only one but I don’t really think I understood how to use the shell block within a snakefile. Additionnally, this is not very elegant I think, especially because each run sequenced a batch of 96 samples  and therefore, the pipeline will have to be changed for every batch of 96 samples. There’s the pipeline I’ve engineered:

```
(SAMPLES,IDS,RUNS,TAGS,SSS,LANES,PAIRED,) = glob_wildcards(config["dataDirInput"]+"{samp}/{id}_run[run]_[tag]_[ss]_L[lane]_R{paire}_001.fastq.gz")

rule all:
  input: 
    expand(config["dataDirOutput"]+"{samp}/{id}_merged.bam", zip, samp = SAMPLES, id = IDS) 

rule trimmomatic:
  input: 
    read1=expand(config["dataDirInput"]+"{samp}/{id}_run[run]_[tag]_[ss]_L[lane]_R1_001.fastq.gz", zip, samp = SAMPLES, id = IDS, run = RUNS, tag = TAGS, ss = SSS, lane = LANES),
    read2=expand(config["dataDirInput"]+"{samp}/{id}_run[run]_[tag]_[ss]_L[lane]_R2_001.fastq.gz", zip, samp = SAMPLES, id = IDS, run = RUNS, tag = TAGS, ss = SSS, lane = LANES)
  output: 
    read1_paired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{samp}/{id}_run[run]_L[lane]_R1_001_paired.fastq.gz",
    read1_unpaired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{samp}/{id}_run[run]_L[lane]_R1_001_unpaired.fastq.gz",
    read2_paired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{samp}/{id}_run[run]_L[lane]_R2_001_paired.fastq.gz",
    read2_unpaired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{samp}/{id}_run[run]_L[lane]_R2_001_unpaired.fastq.gz"
  threads: 20
  resources:
    mem_mb = 20,
    time_min = 300
  params: 
    env=config["trimmomatic_env"]
  shell: "{params.env} PE {input.read1} {input.read2} {output.read1_paired} {output.read1_unpaired} {output.read2_paired} {output.read2_unpaired} ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq3-PE.fa:2:30:10:2:True
 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 MINLEN:36" 
 
 
rule mapping:
  input:  
    read1_paired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{samp}/{id}_run[run]_L[lane]_R1_001_paired.fastq.gz", 
    read2_paired=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{samp}/{id}_run[run]_L[lane]_R2_001_paired.fastq.gz"
  output: 
    mapped=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{sample}/{id}_run[run]_L[lane]_mapped.bam"
  threads: 20
  resources:
    mem_mb = 20,
    time_min = 300
  params: 
    env=config["bwa_env"]
  shell:"{params.env} mem -t 8 /store/EQUIPES/MRP/Partage/Arabidopsis_commun/Genome_sequences/REF_genomes/TAIR10_chr_all.fasta {input.read1_paired} {input.read2_paired} > {output.mapped}"


rule merging: 
   input:  
     mapped_L1_run1=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{sample}/{id}_run757_L001_mapped.bam", # here, run757 and run758 won't be present in every samples, sometimes only one
     mapped_L2_run1=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{sample}/{id}_run757_L002_mapped.bam", # therefore, I think snakemake will miss two inputs when there's a single run
     mapped_L1_run2=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{sample}/{id}_run758_L001_mapped.bam", # and therefore, won't be able to continue the job
     mapped_L2_run2=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{sample}/{id}_run758_L002_mapped.bam"
   output:  
     merged=config["dataDirOutput"]+"{sample}/{id}_merged.bam"
   threads: 20
   resources:
     mem_mb = 20,
     time_min = 300
   params: 
     env=config["samtools_env"]
   shell:"
   shopt -nullglob  
   for file in config["dataDirOutput"]+"{samp}" 
   do
        i=$((i+1))
   done
   n = 6    
   if [ $i = $n ]
   then 
    {params.env} merge {output.merged} {input.mapped_L1_run1} {input.mapped_L2_run1}
  
   else
    {params.env} merge {output.merged} {input.mapped_L1_run1} {input.mapped_L2_run1} {input.mapped_L1_run2} {input.mapped_L2_run2}
  
   fi
  
   "
```

Overall, I think my understanding of the use of wildcards is pretty poor and the way I use it is very inefficient and I would like to know if you would have any tips to overcome my problem and improve it, thanks.

Comment: Since you asked for suggestions, you may wish to look at a recent blog post by Titus Brown, [Snakemake for doing bioinformatics - using wildcards to generalize your rules](http://ivory.idyll.org/blog/2023-snakemake-slithering-wildcards.html).